# ExtJS 4.2.1 -take and restore snapshot of component

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

i got a Panel where i do have alternating components in it.
I want to take a specific snapshot of the Component and then i do want to restore it sometimes. 
Something like that:

```
takeSnapshot: function(){
    var me = this,
        panel = me.getRemarkPanel();

    if(panel){
        var content = panel.getRemarkContainer(),
            currRows = content.query('> editorremarkline');

            var snapshot = {
                remarkLines: Ext.clone(currRows),
                dirtyCmp: Ext.clone(panel.dirtyCmp),
                removedRemarks: Ext.clone(panel.removedRemarks)
            };

        return snapshot;
    }
},

restoreSnapshot: function(snapshot){
    var me = this,
        panel = me.getRemarkPanel();


    if(panel && snapshot){
        var content = panel.getRemarkContainer();

        me.suspendLayouts();

        content.removeAll();
        content.add(snapshot.remarkLines);
        panel.dirtyCmp = snapshot.dirtyCmp;
        panel.removedRemarks = snapshot.removedRemarks;

        me.resumeLayouts(true);
    }
}
```

Though on restoring my Snapshot i get an error when rendering children.
I guess i cant just clone my components clear them up and add them again.

Is there any solution to approach such a thing?  Please help

Comment: "A panel with alternating components" sounds like you could just use a card layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a solution... the key is to clone my components with the method cloneConfig() like this:

```
takeSnapshot: function(){
    var me = this,
        panel = me.getRemarkPanel();

    if(panel){
        var content = panel.getRemarkContainer(),
            currRows = content.query('> editorremarkline'),
            remarkLines = [],
            i = 0;

            for(; i<currRows.length; i++){
                remarkLines.push(currRows[i].cloneConfig());
            }

            var snapshot = {
                remarkLines: remarkLines,
                dirtyCmp: Ext.clone(panel.dirtyCmp),
                removedRemarks: Ext.clone(panel.removedRemarks)
            };
        return snapshot;
    }
},
```